# How to create TabBar like ToggleButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**What I want:**

I want to create a button like the one on `TabBar();` , where it's like a `ToggleButton()` with an underline.

images: [image: This is what I want to achieve.]

[image: The same can be seen on Instagram's account page.]

well, The functionality of this button should be similar to `ToggleButton(),` [refer here. for toggleButton class.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html)

**What I have Tried so far:**

```
                    ToggleButtons(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                            text: "Today",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      "    ${offline.length.toString()}  Slots",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                            text: "Today",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      "    ${offline.length.toString()}  Slots",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      isSelected: isSelected,
                      onPressed: (int index) {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                                buttonIndex < isSelected.length;
                                buttonIndex++) {
                              if (buttonIndex == index) {
                                isSelected[buttonIndex] = true;
                              } else {
                                isSelected[buttonIndex] = false;
                              }
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

*output of the above code:*

[image: Output of my code.]

Comment: Have you tried with tabbar?

Comment: Well i have tried doing that as well, TabBar require TabBarView and my widget is deep inside the widget tree, so using tabbar is not possible for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have only created a `Custom Toggle Button` with all the functionality like `onTap`, `call the function`. I hope this will solve your problem please have a look at below example

[image]

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CustomToggleButton(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomToggleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomToggleButtonState createState() => _CustomToggleButtonState();
}

const double width = 300.0;
const double height = 60.0;
const double todayAlign = -1;
const double signInAlign = 1;
const Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
const Color normalColor = Colors.black38;

class _CustomToggleButtonState extends State<CustomToggleButton> {
  double xAlign;
  Color todayColor;
  Color tomorrowColor;
  bool selectedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    xAlign = todayAlign;
    todayColor = selectedColor;
    tomorrowColor = normalColor;
    selectedValue = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                width: width,
                height: 100,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(00.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    AnimatedAlign(
                      alignment: Alignment(xAlign, 0),
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: width * 0.5,
                        height: 70,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            // color: Colors.pink,
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Colors.white,
                                Colors.white,
                                Colors.white,
                                Colors.white,
                                Colors.pink
                              ],
                              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              // stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                              // tileMode: TileMode.clamp
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          xAlign = todayAlign;
                          todayColor = selectedColor;
                          tomorrowColor = normalColor;
                          selectedValue = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: width * 0.5,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: "Today",
                              style: TextStyle(color: todayColor, fontSize: 15),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: "    2 Slots",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          xAlign = signInAlign;
                          tomorrowColor = selectedColor;
                          selectedValue = false;
                          todayColor = normalColor;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(1, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: width * 0.5,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: "Tomorrow",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: tomorrowColor, fontSize: 15),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: "    3 Slots",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 20,
              ),
             Expanded(
               child:  Container(
                 child: selectedValue ? Text("Today Data") : Text(" Tomorrow Data"),
               ),
             )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, This is not exactly what I am looking for but this is  close enough for my need, hope you understand.

Comment: Yes Yes I know :) Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I have found a package that you can use for that which is the [flutter_toggle_tab](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_toggle_tab). I am sure this could help somehow